# mvc3 - how can I keep a bool from being reset to false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a bool in a view model class. I have an if statement checking to see if the bool is true or false. If false I set the value to true and call a view. In the view I have button that when clicked updates and calls the view again. My problem is that the bool keeps being set to false when the view is loaded. I don't know why this is happening. Is there a way to stop the bool from being changed?

Comment: if you could shows us your some relevant part of your code we can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC is stateless, so the model instance isn't persisted between server calls (unless you are doing this manually, e. g. by saving to the database). Assuming your model is an argument to your action method, the only ways that a value will be popluted in that model is if it is (1) the default value for that property (false in your case), (2) in the url of the request or (3) if it is an input on a submitted form.

If the button that reloads the view does a form submission, you could persist the value by doing

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BoolProperty)
```

in your view. If the button refreshes the page by calling a url, you will have to add the bool property to the url as a route value:

```
var url = Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { m.BoolProperty });
```

Comment: The view I've been given to work with is a .aspx view with the "value" attribute of the input tag already being used. As far as I can tell I'm unable to add a property to the input tag. 

`<input type="submit" class="button" value="bvCalc" />`

Comment: Since you haven't provided any code to actually review beyond `bcCalc` which we have no how it is calculated, this is a really good answer.

Comment: Keep in mind this answer works provided you're using .cshtml. This does not work if you're using .aspx.